# Lower bound related to Hölder's inequality for finite sums.

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, soft-question

Hölder's inequality for finite sums is given by
$$\sum_{k=0}^n|a_kb_k|\leq\left(\sum_{k=0}^n|a_k|^p\right)^{1/p}\left(\sum_{k=0}^n|b_k|^q\right)^{1/q},$$
where $1/p+1/q=1$, $p,q\in(1,\infty)$.

Is there a "similar" inequality which gives a lower bound for the left hand sum? I have searched, but found nothing so far.

Comment: Suppose $(a_n) = 0,1,0,1, \dots, (b_n) = 1,0,1,0, \dots$

Comment: Obviously zero is a lower bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the corresponding lower bound is 
$$
\max(|a_k b_k|)
$$
which is not very interesting because it squelches $p$ and $q$, but it saturates so we can't produce a more interesting lower bound.

Answer (score 0):

Just consider Cauchy-Schwarz. We see that
\begin{align}
|a_1b_1 + a_2b_2| \leq \sqrt{a_1^2+a_2^2}\sqrt{b_1^2+b_2^2}.
\end{align}
If you are hoping for estimates of the nature
\begin{align}
f\left(\sqrt{a_1^2+a_2^2}, \sqrt{b_1^2+b_2^2}\right) \leq |a_1b_1+a_2b_2|
\end{align}
for some function $f(x, y)$ which is nonnegative on $\{x \geq 0, y\geq 0\}$, then you better hope if $(a_1, a_2)\perp (b_1, b_2)$ you have
\begin{align}
f\left(\sqrt{a_1^2+a_2^2}, \sqrt{b_1^2+b_2^2}\right) \leq 0.
\end{align}
Well. Guess $f$ has to be trivial.